# Expanding a variable in Bash as a parameter to rsync

Tags: bash, rsync

I tried to write a very simple synchronizing script that uses rsync with some params.
I wanted these params to be stored in a variable in my script.
Here is a minimal example:

```
$tree
.
├── a
│   └── aaa_p=1_k=1
│       └── x.txt
├── b
│   └── aaa_p=1_k=1
│       └── x.txt
└── script.sh

$cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash

PARAMS="--exclude '*p=*'"
rsync -av ${PARAMS} ./a/* ./b/
```

But when I run `script.sh`, it synchronizes `x.txt`, although `x.txt` it resides in a path containing `p=` that should be excluded. At the same time, when I run from command line:
`rsync -av --exclude '*p=*' ./a/* ./b/`
then the `exclude` is respected, and synchronization does not happen.

What do I do badly in the script, so the `exclude` switch is not taken into account? Is it variable substitution in Bash?

Comment: Use an array to store the value of `PARAMS`  i.e. Change `PARAMS="--exclude '*p=*'"` to `PARAMS=(--exclude '*p=*')` , then `rsync ... "${PARAMS[@]}"` ...

Comment: Thank you, seems like my question was a duplicate, I did research earlier on SO, but somehow the keywords I used didn't lead me to the already existing threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `--exclude '*p=*' ./a/* ./b/` in your terminal the `'` quotes are removed by bash. `rsync` sees only the string `*p=*`. But when you write `PARAMS="--exclude '*p=*'"; rsync -av ${PARAMS}` the quotes inside the variable stay, telling `rsync` to exlcude files that start and end with a `'`.

You could leave out the `'` quotes inside the variable, but the `*` would expand before `rsync` runs (this was also the case before, but `'*p*'` probably didn't match any file). You could quote `"$PARAMS"` to avoid expanding `*`, but then the whole string `--exclude *p=*` would be treated as one argument.

The correct way to go about this is to use an array:

```
params=(--exclude '*p=*')
rsync -av "${params[@]}" ./a/* ./b/
```